# Out of Memory error occurs when running unit tests within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

I have fixed my issue BUT I don't understand why my fix worked. I was hoping someone could help me understand the underlining root cause.

I'm working on a NETCore 6.0 application for a web API, when running unit tests locally within Visual Studio about 95% of the tests fail due to a "System out of memory" error. However, the build pipeline within Azure DevOps worked fine without any issue. The stack trace didn't provide any more insights unfortunately. After reading lots of articles and not getting anywhere, I resorted to changing options one by one until something happened. I found that turning the following setting within Visual Studio to FALSE fixed the issue: "Test Explorer window > Options > Configure Run Settings > Auto Detect runsettings File"

**My Question:** Why would setting this option to FALSE fix the issue?

Error text:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

.runnsettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                        <ModulePaths>
                            <Include>
                                <ModulePath>.*myapp.*.dll</ModulePath>
                            </Include>
                            <Exclude>
                                <ModulePath>.*moq.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*nunit3.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*xunit.*</ModulePath>
                            </Exclude>
                        </ModulePaths>
                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```